# How to change host in curl snippet in Spring REST Docs

Tags: spring-restdocs

Spring REST Docs produces a curl snippet which is very convenient when testing. It is equivalent to the `MockMvc` call as said in its docs but it would be good if its host part can be replaced with a test server's hostname (including port) instead of `localhost`. Is it possible to achieve it with the current version of it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can configure the host (and scheme and port) when you create the MockMvc instance:

```
this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context)
        .apply(documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation).uris()
                .withScheme("https")
                .withHost("example.com")
                .withPort(443))
        .build();
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed it already documented in http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html5/#configuration-uris

Answer (score 8):

Using SpringBoot and autoconfiguration it could be:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc    
@AutoConfigureRestDocs(uriScheme = "https", uriHost = "myhost", uriPort = "80")
public class Test { 

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    ...
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't worked for me, while manual configuration do the trick.